# How to get the_category(', ') with link "title" attribute

Tags: categories

In my theme I use `<?php echo the_category(', '); ?>` to get the categories, separates by comma, with links to them. But those links have no title attribute. Is there any way to get them?

Comment: What do you need it for? A title attribute for a link that already has the same text is redundant, and it [doesn't actually help accessibility or SEO](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/dont-rely-title-attribute-accessibility-seo/).

Comment: What should that title attr contain?

Comment: I wanna reduce SEO title and alt errors... So alt and title could contain just name of the category. But now I think it's not worth of the work...

Answer (score 0):

There are no filters in [`get_the_category_list`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L128) function, that will allow you to add title attribute to those links, so you'll have to write your own code for that...

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach ( $categories as $i => $cat ) :
        if ( $i ) echo ', ';
?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ); ?>" ><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Do you think should I care of alt and title attributes for links to categories?

Comment: It depends... If you want to put description of a cetegory in there, then it makes some sense as usability feature. But if you want to put a name of a cetegory in there, then no, you shouldn't even bother...